# Unclosed character literal in java

Tags: java

I'm new to java and when I tried to print basic hello world program. I am getting following error "Error:(11, 12) java: unclosed character literal "

```
package com.company;

public class Main {
public static void main(String[] args) {

    //declare a variable

    char a;
    a = 'helloworld';
    System.out.println("type the char value: " + a);
 }
}
```

Can you please let me know where did I made a mistake ?

Comment: char take one charcter

Answer (score 3):

Single quotes can only take one character.

Change the data type to `String`

```
String a = "helloworld";
```

`String` represents a *string of characters*.

See docs: [`String`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/String.html) and [`Data types`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/nutsandbolts/datatypes.html)

Comment: Thanks thegauravmahawar !!

Answer (score 1):

First off, the "char" data type can only take a single character. What you're looking for is the "String" data type.

Secondly, as a note on the first, if you create a String you'll need to use double quotes "" rather than single quotes ''.

Comment: Thanks VortixDev !!

Answer (score 1):

First of all you have to understand all the **datatype**.

`char` is use for only store one char

`String`  is use for store many char

**1st way**

`String a = "helloWorld";`

**2nd way**

```
char a[] = {'h', 'e', 'l', 'l', 'o', 'W', 'o', 'r', 'l', 'd'};

for(char c : a)
     System.out.print(c);
```

**3rd way**

```
System.out.println("HelloWorld");
```

among all these 1st one is perfect